# How to spy a "t" function in react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, i18next

I need to test this scenario:

- in component:

```js
t("some.key", { name: "Ash" })
```

- in json:

```json
{ "some": { "key": "Hi {{name}}" }
```

I would like to spy "t" function and get in the tests what parameters was passed and what was returned.

some like this:

```js
expect(spyed).toHaveBeenCaledWith("some.key", { name: "Ash" })
expect(spyed).toHaveReturnedWith("Hi Ash")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is a bad practice to make your assertions on implementation details.

`i18next` as a special mode, called [`cimode`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage), which will make your `t` function to return the key itself. This allows your test to make the assertions on the outcome of your actions (check that the element contains the key value).